# Cv2.error: OpenCV 4.7.0 and overload resolution failed Python 3.x

Tags: pytorch, opencv, facenet, python

I'm doing a project involving cv2 and PyTorch and whenever facenet detects a face, it is supposed to put a rectangle around it. Here's the code that is resulting in the error:

```
for i, prob in enumerate(prob_list):
            if prob>0.90:
                emb = resnet(img_cropped_list[i].unsqueeze(0)).detach() 
                
                dist_list = [] # list of matched distances, minimum distance is used to identify the person
                
                for idx, emb_db in enumerate(embedding_list):
                    dist = torch.dist(emb, emb_db).item()
                    dist_list.append(dist)

                min_dist = min(dist_list) # get minumum dist value
                min_dist_idx = dist_list.index(min_dist) # get minumum dist index
                name = name_list[min_dist_idx] # get name corrosponding to minimum dist
                
                box = boxes[i] 
                
                original_frame = frame.copy() # storing copy of frame before drawing on it
                
                if min_dist<0.90:
                    frame = cv2.putText(frame, name+' '+str(min_dist), (box[0],box[1]), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0,255,0),1, cv2.LINE_AA)
                
                frame = cv2.rectangle(frame, (box[0],box[1]) , (box[2],box[3]), (255,0,0), 2)
```

Whenever I tried running the program, a cv2 window displays as expected but whenever facenet detects a face, cv2 does not put a rectangle over it and the program terminates and puts out this error:

```
File "/home/.../Desktop/facedetect/test.py", line 80, in <module>
    frame = cv2.rectangle(frame, (box[0],box[1]) , (box[2],box[3]), (255,0,0), 2)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.7.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'rectangle'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - Can't parse 'pt1'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type
>  - Can't parse 'pt1'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type
>  - Can't parse 'rec'. Expected sequence length 4, got 2
>  - Can't parse 'rec'. Expected sequence length 4, got 2
```

Comment: Make sure the elements in `box` are integers. OpenCV can only draw using integer values. The error here is telling me, most likely, `box` is filled with floats so opencv is refusing to draw it.

Comment: Thank you, I made the element in box ints. works very well now